# Angular disable button based on checkbox from partial view

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app in which i am using routing. In my template, i have a button defined as follows:

```
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="!checked" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
```

In the template i have in my partial view which is called in the `ui-sref`, i have the following:

```
Click me to toggle: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">
```

So i would like to know how to enable and disable the button in the parent template based on the checkbox in the partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So the question over here is how to transport the value from child to parent 
so there are multiple ways to achieve so:**

One in the child where you have ng-model, point the checked variable to parent checked variable.

What I mean is use something this way 
Click me to toggle: `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.checked">` or 
`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.$parent.checked">` based upon the heirarchy.

**Second could be a easy fix but be sure with unique names:**

use $rootScope. see `$scope` has it visibility between a view and controller but `$rootScope` has its visibility or life of `$rootScope` is valid  for entire Angular Module.

Hope this help .